# d3.json works but $.getJson fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, d3.js

Using [d3.json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests) to make a json request works while $.getJson and $.ajax fail. It is not a cross-domain problem as I am requesting a script on the same domain.

```
d3.json('api.php?q=/user/authUser?authemail=email%26authpassword=pass', function(d) {

        console.log(d);

});
```

In console --> network, the d3 request correctly shows api.php as the path but with $.getJson or $.ajax I get the web service route (web.myapp.local) as the path.

Isn't d3.json just a wrapper for $.getJson. If so, why is the request path different for each.

Comment: D3 is completely independent from jQuery, so it is not a wrapper. Try the URL with a preceding `/` (to make it absolute).

Comment: Instead of getting the json back like I do with d3, the response with $.ajax or $.getJson is the index.php page. I've fiddled with the url and that doesn't do it

Comment: Figured out the problem - I was using mockjax, a javascript library to intercept ajax calls and it was causing the problems. Solved it by completely removing the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, I was using mockjax, a javascript library to intercept ajax calls and it was causing the problems. Solved it by completely removing the library.

This might not be a problem with the latest releases - but it was at the time